# Assigning values out of block with GCD xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I am using amazon web services to upload images. I am not able to access a value out of the GCD block. How should i access the value of "myString" in some other class?

My code:

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
{
    AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if(indicatorView!=nil)
    {
        [indicatorView removeFromSuperview];
        indicatorView=nil;
    }

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Upload Completed" message:@"The image was successfully uploaded." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

    //del.fileName = url;

    // Set the content type so that the browser will treat the URL as an image.
    /*S3ResponseHeaderOverrides *override = [[S3ResponseHeaderOverrides alloc] init];
    override.contentType = @"image/jpeg";

    // Request a pre-signed URL to picture that has been uplaoded.
    S3GetPreSignedURLRequest *gpsur = [[S3GetPreSignedURLRequest alloc] init];
    gpsur.key = @"NameOfThePicture";
    //del.fileName = gpsur.key;
    gpsur.bucket = @"pic-bucket";
    gpsur.expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSTimeInterval) 3600]; // Added an hour's worth of seconds to the current time.

    gpsur.responseHeaderOverrides = override;

    // Get the URL
    NSError *error;
    url = [self.s3 getPreSignedURL:gpsur error:&error];
    NSString *myString = [url absoluteString];

    NSLog(@"myStringgg====>%@",myString);
    del.fileName = myString;
    NSLog(@"URL=====>%@",url);*/



    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^
    {

        // Set the content type so that the browser will treat the URL as an image.
        S3ResponseHeaderOverrides *override = [[S3ResponseHeaderOverrides alloc] init];
        override.contentType = @"image/jpeg";

        // Request a pre-signed URL to picture that has been uplaoded.
        S3GetPreSignedURLRequest *gpsur = [[S3GetPreSignedURLRequest alloc] init];
        gpsur.key = @"NameOfThePicture";
        //del.fileName = gpsur.key;
        gpsur.bucket = @"pic-bucket";
        gpsur.expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSTimeInterval) 3600]; // Added an hour's worth of seconds to the current time.

        gpsur.responseHeaderOverrides = override;

        // Get the URL
        NSError *error;
        NSURL *url = [self.s3 getPreSignedURL:gpsur error:&error];
        NSString *myString = [url absoluteString];
        //del.fileName = myString;
        NSLog(@"URL=====>%@",url);

        if(url == nil)
        {
            if(error != nil)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                    //[self showAlertMessage:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"message"] withTitle:@"Browser Error"];
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                //del.fileName = myString;

                //NSLog(@"haURL===>%@",del.fileName);
            });

            del.fileName = myString;
        }


    //NSLog(@"nameURL====>%@",url);
    });




}
```

Now i want to access "myString" var so that i can access its value in other class. Thanks

Property declarations:

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *fileName;  //in appdelegate.h
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *File;     //in the same controller as GCD

Update:

```
    PictureViewController *pic = [[PictureViewController alloc]init];


        **NSLog(@"newNameeee====>%@",pic.File);**


        AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        NSLog(@"LocatedAt====>%@",del.locatedAt);


        NSLog(@"FileSize====>%d",del.fileSize);
        **NSLog(@"FileName====>%@",del.fileName);**
```

Comment: you are assigning the value of myString to del.fileName. Why don't you use that variable.

Comment: i am using it but it returns null when i access it in my other class

Comment: Sorry I looked through your code again and it appears that I misunderstood your problem. I'll delete my answer and come back on that...

Comment: Could you add the code in your other class where you're trying to access the `del.FileName`?

Comment: Please add it to your answer not in the comment, it's very hard to read here. And while at it you could use the opportunity to clean up the code in your answer, i.e. remove the comments etc. ;)

Comment: Btw.: why are you executing that block asynchronous anyway? It seams that the method you're doing that in already is a callback from an asynchronous execution and the code doesn't look like there's something time consuming going on, is it?

Comment: Actually i am uploading images to amazon S3 and their own code sample uses async blocks so dats why

Comment: What part of that block starts the upload? Sry I'm not familiar with the amazon webservice

Comment: this block is just used for requesting a pre-signed URL to picture that has been uplaoded.

Comment: Ok. So back to your problem. I'm guessing that you try to access `del.fileName` before the async part of your other method finished.

Comment: I also think that dats why m getting null in other controller.

Comment: What happens if you uncomment the part `del.fileName = myString; NSLog(@"haURL===>%@",del.fileName);` in the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` block. Does it log out the value or still null?

Comment: Ah ok, just as I expected. I'll add a new answer with the solution (hopefully) ;)

Comment: Thanks tobi for taking out time for me...Waiting for your solution:)

Comment: I hope you understand what I mean in my answer. It's hard to describe since I don't know your entire code. If you're still stuck you could post the entire code of your AppDelegate.h/.m and PictureViewController.h/.m at [Gist](https://gist.github.com) and I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you try to access the `del.fileName` before the async part of the `request:didCompleteWithResponse:` finishes.

Try the following: modify your code slightly be moving the `del.fileName = myString` to the dispatch block on the main tread:

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
{
    AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if(indicatorView!=nil)
    {
        [indicatorView removeFromSuperview];
        indicatorView=nil;
    }

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Upload Completed" message:@"The image was successfully uploaded." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^
    {

        // Set the content type so that the browser will treat the URL as an image.
        S3ResponseHeaderOverrides *override = [[S3ResponseHeaderOverrides alloc] init];
        override.contentType = @"image/jpeg";

        // Request a pre-signed URL to picture that has been uplaoded.
        S3GetPreSignedURLRequest *gpsur = [[S3GetPreSignedURLRequest alloc] init];
        gpsur.key = @"NameOfThePicture";
        //del.fileName = gpsur.key;
        gpsur.bucket = @"pic-bucket";
        gpsur.expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSTimeInterval) 3600]; // Added an hour's worth of seconds to the current time.

        gpsur.responseHeaderOverrides = override;

        // Get the URL
        NSError *error;
        NSURL *url = [self.s3 getPreSignedURL:gpsur error:&error];
        NSString *myString = [url absoluteString];
        //del.fileName = myString;
        NSLog(@"URL=====>%@",url);

        if(url == nil)
        {
            if(error != nil)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                    //[self showAlertMessage:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"message"] withTitle:@"Browser Error"];
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                del.fileName = myString;
                [del didReceivePictureFilename];
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Than you declare the `didReceivePictureFilename` in your `AppDelegate` and move the accessing part of your code to that method. But you have to do the part where you start the upload some place else. (The code in your question doesn't show that part)

Of course you could also omit the `fileName` property entirely and hand the filename directly in the `didReceivePictureFilename` callback:

```
[del didReceivePictureFilename:myString];
```